# Go: Unmarshaling results from Neo4j transaction

Tags: json, go, neo4j, unmarshalling

I'm trying to figure out the best way to unmarshal the JSON results that you get from a Neo4j transaction.  The data comes back as a set of columns and data which I'm trying to shoehorn into a Go struct.

Here is my struct that I need the results to end up in:

```
type Person struct {
  Id   string `json:id`
  Name string `json:name`
}

type Persons []*Person
```

And here is the JSON that I'm getting back from my transaction:

```
{
  "results":
  [
    {"columns":[],"data":[]},  
    {"columns":[],"data":[]},
    {"columns":[],"data":[]},
    {"columns":["r"],"data":   // I only care this result which has data
      [
        {"row":[{"id":"1","name":"test1"}]},  // actual results
        {"row":[{"id":"2","name":"test2"}]},
        {"row":[{"id":"3","name":"test3"}]}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors":[]
}
```

This is just one particular example. Other transactions will have variable numbers of `results` (only the last of which I ever care about) and will need to be unmarshalled into different structs.  I don't want to create have to create a unique result struct for every model struct.  Here is another example:

Here is a different struct:

```
type Phone struct {
  Id     string `json:id`
  Number string `json:number`
}

type Phones []*Phone
```

And the corresponding JSON:

```
{
  "results":
  [
    {"columns":[],"data":[]},  
    {"columns":["r"],"data":   // I only care this result which has data
      [
        {"row":[{"id":"4","number":"555-1234"}]},  // actual results
        {"row":[{"id":"5","number":"555-1232"}]},
        {"row":[{"id":"6","number":"555-1235"}]}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors":[]
}
```

Currently I just read out the entire response, fix up the format using string replaces and then unmarshal normally but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

**Here is the current implementation that I'm looking to improve.**

```
// Structures to unmarshal Neo4j transaction results into.
type transactionResponse struct {
    Results *json.RawMessage   `json:"results"`
    Errors  []transactionError `json:"errors"`
}

// req is my POST to Neo4j 
resp, err := db.client.Do(req)
defer resp.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Error posting transaction: %s", err)
}

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

var txResponse transactionResponse
if err = json.Unmarshal(body, &txResponse); err == nil {
    json.Unmarshal(formatTransactionResponse(*txResponse.Results), &Phones{});
}    

func formatTransactionResponse(data []byte) []byte {
    start := bytes.Index(data, []byte("[\"r\"]")) + 13
    data = data[start:]
    data = bytes.Replace(data, []byte("{\"row\":["), nil, -1)
    data = bytes.Replace(data, []byte("}]},{"), []byte("},{"), -1)
    data = bytes.TrimSuffix(data, []byte("}]}]"))

    //special case if no results are returned
    if len(data) == 4 {
        data = bytes.TrimSuffix(data, []byte("}]"))
    }

    return data
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the Neo4j output is itself a well-formed JSON structure, you could unmarhsal it to its own struct:

```
type Phone struct {
    Id     string `json:"id"`
    Number string `json:"number"`
}

type Output struct {
    Results []struct {
        Columns []string `json:"columns"`
        Data    []struct {
            Row []Phone `json:"row"`
        } `json:"data"`
    } `json:"results"`
    Errors []string `json:"errors"`
}

o := Output{}
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &o)
```

And then you do whatever you want with that structure.

```
for _, result := range o.Results {
    if len(result.Data) > 0 {
        // Here are your phones.
        for _, d := range result.Data {
            fmt.Println(d.Row)
        }
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/tWc677HX1V

Your ugly-ish function, though, will probably be faster, if you need that.

Comment: But then I'll need an Output struct for every one of my models (which there are 30+ of) and I'll have to do post processing of the results since this will return a slice of phone slices when I really just want a straight slice of phones. And after all that, it will be slower as well...

Comment: You could alternatively unmarshal into a `map[string]interface{}` and assert-as-you-go. This is prone to programming errors, though.

Comment: This seems like a lot more work and as you say, would be pretty error prone.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following article: http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go, "Decoding arbitrary data" section.

You can decode a json into a map with string keys and then use this map to access data you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no good way to deal with such a verbose protocol. But the best solution is probably a cross between yours and the one in Toni's answer, something like this:

```
type transactionResponse struct {
    Results []struct {
        Columns []string
        Data    []struct {
            Row []json.RawMessage
        }
    }
    Errors []string
}
```

This would eliminate the string processing of the JSON, while still only requiring one new type to be defined. You could probably write a function to efficiently extract the data you need from this structure and unmarshal it.

Comment: The problem I ran into doing this way is that then my database needs to know more about the results. Currently I pass in a reference to a slice of results (&Persons) and the db code unmarshals directly into that. It doesn't need to know anything about the result format. As soon as you unmarshal into a RawMessage, the db needs to know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't deal with unmarshalling this manually, just use the standard go database APIs and the cq driver:

https://github.com/wfreeman/cq

Then you can use sqlx which does automatic unmarshalling into structs for you:

https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx

This allows you to benefit from the optimizations in both sqlx for struct mapping and in cq for batching requests, as well as all future improvements from both libraries.

Something like this:

```
import (
    _ "github.com/wfreeman/cq"
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "log"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string `db:"first_name"`
    Email     string
}

func main() {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("neo4j-cypher", "http://localhost:7474")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    people := []Person{}
    db.Select(&people, "MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n.name AS first_name, n.email AS email")
}
```

Comment: There is this warning in `cq`: `Please let me know if any issues arise from using sqlx with cq--it is not thoroughly tested`. They both also assume you are using the standard Cypher return format whereas I only return nested literal maps. Plus it seems like overkill to use the `sqlx` library to make HTTP requests. My goal, eventually, is to be able to seamlessly stream data from Neo4j directly into Go structs with no middleman. Unfortunately the Neo4j result format is broken so I need a way to work around it until it is fixed, not add a bunch of new dependencies.

Comment: @Bill What is it about the result format that makes you say it's broken?

Comment: @Bill would love more detailed feedback on the result format and what we could do to improve it. You're right sqlx is not tested with cq, but we use it in a large OS project, and it works a charm there: https://github.com/trusthoarder/hockeypuck

Comment: On the topic of overhead, you're right sqlx means you need to unmarshall to an intermediary structure before sqlx maps it. I'd still go with it though, most of the overhead I'm seeing in the wild are elsewhere - lack of batching requests, cost of re-establishing TCP connections if using "regular" HTTP clients, not using streaming deserialization, and so on. As long as the deserialization of the response is using a streaming JSON parser, the cost of copying it into a struct is counted in nanoseconds, compared to hundreds of microseconds for other areas of optimization.

Comment: @jjaderberg The result format is broken because it doesn't return what I ask it to return. My Cypher query says `RETURN {id: x.id, number: x.number}` so I would expect it to return an array of maps using valid JSON (which I could then steam directly into Go structs). Instead I get back a Frankenstein JSON object with `columns` and `data` and `rows` which I definitely didn't ask for.

Comment: @jakewins I sent detailed feedback to Andreas as part of the `FIP - perfect response` document but never heard anything back. I would be happy to send it off to you if you are interested. If the format was fixed there would be no need to unmarshall it into an intermediary structure or take on big dependencies like `cq` and `sqlx` - it would literally take 5 lines of Go to stream the results into the correct structs (or any language with native JSON parsers). The other problem with `cq` is that it doesn't work with returning literal maps, as far as I can tell, which is how I do everything.